# In Pandas I have a dataframe where several columns define a configuration. I want to identify the rows with identical configurations

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, cluster-computing

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [ 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107 ],
                   'color': [ 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue' ],
                   'location': ['there', 'here', 'there', 'here', 'here', 'there', 'here']})

df
```

Out[12]:

```
    id color location
0  101  blue    there
1  102  blue     here
2  103  blue    there
3  104   red     here
4  105  blue     here
5  106   red    there
6  107  blue     here
```

I want to make a column with grouping by color and location, like this:

```
    id color location group
0  101  blue    there     A
1  102  blue     here     B
2  103  blue    there     A
3  104   red     here     C
4  105  blue     here     B
5  106   red    there     D
6  107  blue     here     B
```

Comment: Would it matter if the groups are labeled with letters, or are numbers fine? (Might be a bit easier/safer in the case of more than 26 groups...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `groupby().ngroup()`:

```
df['group'] = df.groupby(['color','location'], sort=False).ngroup()
```

Output:

```
    id color location  group
0  101  blue    there      0
1  102  blue     here      1
2  103  blue    there      0
3  104   red     here      2
4  105  blue     here      1
5  106   red    there      3
6  107  blue     here      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do `factorize`

```
df[['color','location']].agg(','.join,1).factorize()[0]
Out[12]: array([0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1], dtype=int64)
#df['group']=df[['color','location']].agg(','.join,1).factorize()[0]
```